# Google Books API

Tags: android, google-api, google-books

I just started integrating [Google Books API](https://developers.google.com/books/) in my app and its working pretty well, but I have an "issue" that still didn't manage to solve.

When I send a get request, google returns me all data related, and I'm just gonna use a few of those fields, so that creates a bandwidth waste.

I looked at the documentation and there's a mode called Projection Lite but projection lite skips some of the fields I need. So the question is, is there a way to return only specific fields?

Answer (score 4):

check out [Partial response](https://developers.google.com/books/docs/v1/performance#partial-response) most of the Google APIs support this feature.

By default the API returns all the fields but you can also specify which fields you want returned.

```
https://www.googleapis.com/demo/v1?key=YOUR-API-KEY&fields=kind,items(title,characteristics/length)
```

Sorry cant help with android code.

Comment: exactly what I was look for dude. Looks like I still didn't read the whole documentation. Thank you for the fast answer, you just saved me a lot of time. ^^

Comment: Not your fault stuff like this is hiding in the documentation. Sometimes you have to know "where" to look.

Comment: Yeah. xD Thank you very much